# Typescript does not notice class constructor incompatibility

Tags: typescript

Why in this snippet TypeScript does not notice that `MadeFromString` class does not have a second boolean argument in its constructor and so is not appropriate for `StringConstructable` interface:

```
interface ComesFromString {
  name: string;
}

class MadeFromString implements ComesFromString {
  constructor(public name: string) {
    // Returns an object of type ComesFromString / MadeFromString
  }
}

interface StringConstructable {
  new (n: string, w: boolean): ComesFromString;
}

function makeObj(n: StringConstructable) {
  return new n('hello!', false);
}

const test1 = makeObj(MadeFromString);
```

Yet here, it does notice that `MadeFromString` does not have a boolean variable called `w`:

```
interface ComesFromString {
  name: string;
}

class MadeFromString implements ComesFromString {
  constructor(public name: string) {
    // Returns an object of type ComesFromString / MadeFromString
  }
}

interface StringConstructable {
  new (n: string): ComesFromString;
  w: boolean; // ERROR
}

function makeObj(n: StringConstructable) {
  return new n('hello!', false);
}

const test1 = makeObj(MadeFromString); // ERROR
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. When checking if functions are compatible, typescript enforces that all the right data is being passed in. It does *not* try to make sure that the function does something with that data.

Consider if I wrote the following constructor, but no lines of code used the second argument:

```
constructor(public name: string, neverUsed: boolean) {
  // the variable neverUsed is not used anywhere in the constructor
}
```

Presumably you agree that that should match `StringConstructable`. But the variable is doing nothing. It's common in javascript to leave off variables you don't care about; they'll still be passed in, you just won't access them. And typescript's type system supports this.

For more information see [this page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions)

Comment: Moreover, the second example OP put in the question enforces the fact of a single argument - that's why it yields an error.